# Microsoft Office 2010 program pixelated on Windows 7

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, themes

This is strange.  We've updated the graphics driver but yet it didn't fix the pixelated icons and program window of all Office 2010 applications.  Everything looks pixelated as if it's on Windows 3.0.  We've managed to change the theme of Windows 7 but it didn't change anything.

All the Office 2010 applications look like this
[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: @TuxRug screenshot attached

Comment: Hmm.... This came up as a recent question with a bounty (I think)... I will try to find and see if it was resolved.

Comment: I found this: http://superuser.com/questions/160514/office-visual-studio-stuck-in-256-colour-mode. No solution was reached though. I remember the other one you're talking about @Wil, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @nhinkle Beat me... I was just about to paste that!!!! But there was another one... I can't find it either - I wonder if it was deleted, I know I commented (and I think answered) but even doing a user:me search doesn't show it. Glad you remember as well as I thought I was going mad!

Comment: We established that it had to do with colour depth on the display.

Comment: will try color depth...but is it program specific?

Comment: No, it's Windows-specific.

Comment: Windows 7 looks fine just without transparency.  The icons on the desktop looks normal.  Other softwares have no issues. only Office softwares are the obvious ones.

Comment: Wait.... so what is your color depth set to? Do you not have Aero enabled?

Comment: not sure.  it's not my laptop it's my boss's have to find out monday.

Comment: Hm. Well I just tried setting my color depth to 16-bit and Word still looked normal.

Answer (score 3):

I got this on XP as well. After installing AirDisplay I did a System restore. All is working now.

Comment: it was Airdisplay

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is a year old already,...

Try to uninstall air display support and you'll be happy again,... :-)

(It's the desktop support utility to work with the IPad/Iphone app "Air Display" http://avatron.com/apps/air-display)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the Application thinks High Contrast is on, which can be caused by a number of things, such as the time I managed to make it happen because I recoloured bits of the Aero Theme in Window Colour > Advanced Colour Properties.

My suggestion is to try and reapply the Default Theme again...